# EDMX has no relations present using the database-first approach in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I am using Entity Framework to work against a database using the database-first approach, with an EDMX file representing my database. A problem happened when I changed one property in the database, then when I erased it from the EDMX file and updated it to add it again, it shows up now without the relations to the other tables (Pk-Fk relations).

More Info: 
1. tried connecting from another new project and same result.
2. tried re-creating the database and re creating the pk-fk relation, and same result.
3. tried connecting to another database with edmx, and in this case the relations were present. 
4. in the sql management studio it looks like the relations are present in the tables, as well as in the diagram.

Does anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Does it show any warnings or errors while compiling with the edmx open? I tend not to change existing entities but deleting and re-adding them, it saves you quite some headaches.

Comment: @CodeCaster I did erase it and re-added it.

Comment: You were talking about a property (column?), I mean entities (tables). What happens if you remove all related tables and re-add them through "Update model from database..."?

Comment: @CodeCaster I also tried to create anew edmx file from a new project and still I don't get the relations. It look like something is damaged in the sql db.

Comment: Is the association absent from the store model as well? (Under "Constraints")

Answer (score 0):

When I need to update a table in the edmx it normally creates another .edmx.designer file, if this is happening this could be the reason why the relations doesn't appear. Just delete the older .edmx.designer and it should work again. If this isn't the problem, sorry but I'm new to entity framework, don't know it very well

Comment: I also tried to create a new edmx file from a new project and still I don't get the relations. It look like something is damaged in the sql db

Comment: Try doing some test selects in the DB via MySql to see if the relations are still there, if you can do selects with FKs and PKs then we can exclude the theory of problem in the DB

Comment: I am using tSql. I added "More Info:" in my question for more info that might help.